# There is an unwanted .htaccess file with "Order Allow,Deny" in all my wordpress subfolders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have wordpress 5.6 installed on Directadmin. I have several folders with other CMS installed, like joomla. today I noticed that I can't login to subfolder CMS eg. mysite.com/joomla.
after some hours of searching, I found that in ALL my subfolders there is a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
<FilesMatch ".(phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
```

Order Allow,Deny
allow from all

in subfolders my main htaccess files were removed.

in the main directory, public_html, my main .htaccess was changed to .htaccess.bk and there was a newly generated .htaccess file with the following code inside:

```
<FilesMatch ".(phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(index).php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(wp-load).php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand why it has happened. Is it a kind of hacking? I haven't installed any plugin lately. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Same case happend with the my wordpress blog ,  but this time it directly shows on top area of my website to all users. very risky , but not know actual reason. Might something bug in wordpress , that make advantage to breakout the wordpress security.